# segmentation fault for increment in the array index?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do my homework

Before I can use this line without any problem and no segmentation fault and I don't know why it doesn't work now after I compile my code.

This is how it calls from the `main()`:

```
rb = ascii(back_data[i], phr);
```

This is how data define in the `main()`:

```
char phr[41];

int ascii(const char back[ ], char data[ ]){
  int l = 0, n = 0, i = 0, co = 0;
  char binary_holder[8], char_set;

  binary_holder[0] = '\0';

  l = strlen(back);

  for (i = 0; i <= l; i++){

    if (back[i] == '0' || back[i] == '1' && co < 8){

        binary_holder[co] = back[i];
        co++;
    }
    if(co == 8){

      binary_holder[8] = '\0';
      co = 0;
    }

    char_set = strtol(binary_holder, NULL, 2);

    if (char_set > 31 && char_set != 127){
        data[n++] = char_set;   
    }


  }
```

I forgot to mention that the problem is here and I can't figure out still why

`data[n++] = char_set;`

Comment: Show us the details of `data`

Comment: What's `n` and what is its initial value?

Comment: Why are you calling the same function three times? what is data[], where is it defined ?

Comment: You are confusing cause and effect here.  The increment is not the cause of the seg-fault; you are most likely writing past the end of your array.  Show us the declaration (or last assignment) of `data` and also show us your loop (i.e., where does `n` come from?).  Also, why are you calling `strtol` three times?  Call it once, save the result, and be done with it.

Comment: @Ali: Yet still lacking.  Show us the declaration of `data`.  It could be a problem in `binary_holder` as well (less likely).  Is it a null terminated string?

Comment: @EdS. The `binary_holder` is `binary_holder[0] = '\0';`

Comment: @Ali your sample is still too short. You need to show all symbols - how they're defined and how/what they're assigned.

Comment: @xxbbcc the problem is that those information that it is in main like `data` I can't look at the code all I know is that they are passing an empty array from the main

Comment: Here's a thought - try debugging it.  You could single-step through and find out which access causes the segfaut and with what array indexes etc.

Comment: @Ali if you're trying to write into an uniniitalized (=empty) array, that'll give you segfault. You need to know the length of these arrays to reliably read/write them, otherwise you're possibly accessing memory that's not yours.

Comment: That is what I did and I even tried recode the whole program and yet second time I'm still seeing this problem :(

Comment: @Ali what do you mean "recode the whole program"? If you have access to `main` and the rest of the code, why don't you show the symbols here?

Comment: @xxbbcc if I remove the `++` from it and only write it once it is working though?

Comment: @xxbbcc I mean my whole function, sorry.

Comment: @Ali doesn't matter, it may be pure luck. You need to either debug it through and validate that all your arrays are allocated to at least the number of bytes you're trying to store in them and that you're not trying to read/write beyond the end of them.

Comment: I guess I will need to print all the statement each line and see where is really cause the problem again.

Comment: @Ali how is this function is even called? Why can't you access the `main()` function - I'm having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: @xxbbcc       `rc = scii(back_data[i], phrase);` I was looking from my friends previous semester and found that he got the main and here is how it calls

Comment: @Ali: Well that can't be true because, if it were, the if statement would never be entered (i.e., `if (strtol(binary_holder, NULL, 2) > 31)` would return false).

Comment: @Ali: You need to know the size of the arrays, and you *still* have not shown us how it was allocated in the first place.  Also... use your debugger... really.

Comment: @EdS. This is how `data` define in the main `char phrase[41];` and I'm using UNIX shell to code the program because this is what they want us to do :(

Comment: @Ali: Ok... and what is the value of `n` when it crashes?  I don't even see a loop, what you wrote is equivalent to `data[0] = blah;`, which certainly will not cause a segfault if everything you have said is accurate.

Comment: @EdS. I'm going to update my code from what you guys suggested and result still in segmentation fault.

Comment: Okay I got it works now by actually include that code in another if statement.

Comment: Could these comments be deleted now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like in `ascii(back_data[i], phr);` the first arg is a char instead of a pointer-to-char. This non-pointer is passed to `strlen()` — boom.

Comment: I really didn't get it can you explain a bit?

Comment: To really explain it, can you please give us the declaration of `back_data`?